# How to synchronize caroufredsel with fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, caroufredsel

I would like to synchronize the user-action between a caroufredsel carousel with fancybox-linked images. Are there any tutorials or hints out there? I couldn't find any information of how i should do this.

Clicking on the next button on the opened fancybox should fire the coursel or should change the visible pictures on the carousel.

Comment: It'd be nice if you posted some code so that we can see what you've got so far. When you click the next button how do you know whether it should change the visible picture or the carousel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this was asked a several months ago, but if you are interested in using Fancybox with CarouFredSel check out the following link: http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/examples/carousel-lightbox-tooltip.php.

*The CarouFredSel official website has a few examples on this page and Fancybox is one of them :-)

Hope this helps!

Josh